# How to Use LocaleSpan in Android TextView

Tags: java, android

LocaleSpan is a kind of Span for Android. But I cannot find the proper method to use it. With the following code, I cannot get the required result:

```
SpannableString spannableString13 = new SpannableString("LocaleSpan");
LocaleSpan localeSpan = new LocaleSpan(Locale.JAPAN);
spannableString13.setSpan(localeSpan, 0,4, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
mLocaleSpanTextView.setText(spannableString13);
```

Need your help, pls and thanks.

Comment: Consider the given link. I hope it would help you, achieving your required results. . https://findusages.com/search/android.text.Spannable/getSpanStart$1?offset=39

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @Tehmina I may not find what I need ,but thanks

Comment: @BenP. I just would like to learn how to use LocaleSpan. But when I used it, there is no effect.

Comment: setTextLocale https://youtu.be/x-FcOX6ErdI?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9Gq6FEnSXClhYkWAStbwlC

Comment: @onlyloveyd Did you have any solution that works for you?